# taxonomy tax-name archive

Tags: custom-taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I am creating a taxonomy

```
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => $name->labels->name, //genre
        'singular_name'      => $name->labels->singular_name, //genre 
        'menu_name'          => $name->labels->menu_name //genre
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => $name->args->hierarchical, //true
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => $name->args->show_ui,//true
        'show_admin_column' => $name->args->show_admin_column, //true
        'query_var'         => $name->args->query_var, //true
        'rewrite'           => $name->args->rewrite, // books/genre
    );


    register_taxonomy( $name->name, $name->post_types , $args );
```

This works. Now onto the rewrite.

top level `wordpress/books/genre` is 404.
also `wordpress/genre` is 404.
`wordpress/books/genre/term` works.

Is there a setting i'm missing to create a archive on the top level? I can do a wp rewrite but would prefer to use inbuilt where possible!

Comment: what would that archive show? all posts that have any genre?

Comment: yes exactly all posts with any term from genre.

Comment: there's no archive like that in WordPress, tax archives are just single terms.

Comment: thats what i was thinking :( wp_rewrite it is..thanks for your input!